# Could not find RubyGem rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

```
sh -c 'cd /home/xyz/xyz.com/releases/20120410180718 &&
/home/xyz/.gems/bin/rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
assets:precompile' [out ::] /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:779:in
`report_activate_error' [out ::] : Could not find RubyGem rake (>= 0)
(Gem::LoadError [out ::] ) [out ::] from
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:214:in `activate' [out ::] from
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1082:in `gem' [out ::] from
/home//.gems/bin/rake:18
```

I am using **cap deploy:migrations** command
please help.

this is my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails'
gem "mysql2", "~> 0.3.11"
gem "rake"
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
   gem 'compass-rails'
   gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
   gem 'haml'
   gem 'haml-rails'
   gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
   gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

#Media managment
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'ruby_parser'
gem 'hpricot'


# deployment 
gem 'capistrano'
```

in the server side

```
[ps89405]$ rake --version
rake, version 0.9.2.2
```

update:

running the same command without cap from the server works!

```
[ps89405]$ cd /home//.com/releases/20120410183344 &&    /home//.gems/bin/rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile
[ps89405]$
```

update:
i added
    require "bundler/capistrano"

to my deploy.rb

now i have issue this issue

with this command

> ```
>   cd /home/.com/releases/20120410201511 && bundle install --gemfile
> ```
>
> /home/.com/releases/20120410201511/Gemfile --path
>   /home/.com/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet
>   --without development test

if I use **cap** command I get

```
bundle: command not found
```

and when I run it manually on the server it works fine!

Comment: Dumping your commandline into the question box is not going to get you an answer...

Comment: my dear friend. why you are assuming I am dumping my commandline!!! I think I post enough explanation!

Comment: sorry for missing the command line highlighting. and I also added some more details for you.

Comment: Please add your `deploy.rb` file and the output of `cap deploy:check`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you done `bundle install` on the deployment destination? The error seems to imply that your bundle is not installed.

`Could not find RubyGem rake (>= 0)` means that the take is running in a context where the `rake` gem is not installed.

Comment: yes I have. I run the same command that generates the error manually and it works! but with cap command it fails!

Comment: `sh -c 'cd /home/xyz/xyz.com/releases/20120410180718 &&
/home/xyz/.gems/bin/rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets`  <== this isn't running within the `bundle` context. Change it to `sh -c 'cd /home/xyz/xyz.com/releases/20120410180718 &&
/home/xyz/.gems/bin/bundle rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets` and try again, see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I guess I should ask if you're using `bundler` or not - bad assumption on my part for not asking first.

Comment: how can I do this? should I change the deploy.rb file?

Comment: That's where I would look first, yes.

Comment: can you give me a snippet of the line? I added this line earlier set :rake, "/home/aaalsubaie/.gems/bin/rake"

Comment: sorry this is my first deployment.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9926/discussion-between-normalocity-and-aaalsubaie)